# ReferenceError while configuring Firebase Realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to setup a Firebase Realtime database for my Flask application. I'm using a browser environment without a build step. My frontend is an .html file with some JS for managing sockets and hopefully, database interactions.

The below code produces the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ref

Does anything seem off with how I have the database configured? I'm finding the documentation to be a bit confusing for non-npm uses.

```html
<script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
  import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-database.js";

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const database = getDatabase(app);

  const socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    function loadChatHistory(user_id) {
        const chatRef = ref(database, 'users/' + user_id + '/chats');
        onValue(chatRef, (snapshot) => {
            const chatHistory = snapshot.val();
</script>
```

Comment: Your script appears incomplete. As it appears now, this would throw syntax errors

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]